# We need to test a mixed windows-Linux environment. Is there a automation tool that supports both?

Tags: linux, windows, testing, automation, seetest

We are trying to automate an aplication that lives in a mixed windows-linux environment. We need a test automation tool that supports both environments. Any recommendations?

We are evaluating SeeTest (www.experitest.com) that claims to be capable of supporting both Linux and Windows .
Does anyone have any experience using it for such circumstances? Does SeeTest recording work for Linux as well or only for Windows?

Comment: You might want to look here: http://www.manageability.org/blog/stuff/open-source-automated-test-tools-written-in-java

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what kind of connectivity you have to them and what protocols you want to use to manage them. There are literally hundreds of way to do what you are proposing. I suggest adding more details like...

-What kind of testing are you doing? API? UI? Stability? Performance? 
-What sort of application is it?
-Is one platform representing clients (windows?) and one platform the servers (Linux?)?

There are also tools out there like cygwin, openssh, etc that might accomplish what you are trying to do for free.

-Ryan